# Magento 2 - How to get stock of a product?

Tags: magento2, catalog, inventory

I want to instantiate `CatalogInventory` model in Magento 2 by calling  `loadByProduct()` just like I used to do in Magento 1:

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
```

How can I do this or similar in Magento2?

UPDATED ANSWER:

I have tried getting the stock of a product this way:

```
 use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;
 use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item;

 $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item');
 $stock=$model->loadByProductId(StockItemInterface $item, $productId, $stockId);
```

But I get,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$item' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Let's try my update code.

Answer (score 3):

Look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Item.php`. As we can see, we can use an alternative method `loadByProductId()`. Navigate to `vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/api-functional/testsuite/Magento/CatalogInventory/Api/StockItemTest.php` to see the testing.

```
        $productId = 123456;
        $stockId = 2334;
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory $stockItemFactory */
        $stockItemFactory = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory');
        $stockItem = $stockItemFactory->create();
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item $stockItemResource */
        $stockItemResource = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item');
        $stockItemResource->loadByProductId($stockItem, $productId, $stockId);
```

Comment: Can i call something like this
$stock = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Item')->loadByProductId();

Comment: Can i use this way as given under UPDATED ANSWER

Comment: Any suggestion @Khoa on my updated answer?

Comment: I get exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined variable: productId . i just assigned $stock=$stockItemResource->loadByProductId($stockItem, $productId, $stockId);

Comment: i tried to add $productId=$stockItemFactory->create();, then i get Undefined variable: stockId, if i try to add stockId too then i get exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: addcslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_3\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 296' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_3\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61

Comment: For `$productId` and `$stockId` variables, you can try with some sample values, you can find in `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple get total stock of configurable products using objectManager.

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
$total_stock = 0;
if($_product->getTypeID() == 'configurable'){
    $productTypeInstance = $_product->getTypeInstance();
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($usedProducts as $simple) {
        $total_stock += $StockState->getStockQty($simple->getId(), $simple->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }
}
echo $total_stock;
```

Thanks