# How can we identify whether the class is injectable or not in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager

1. How can we identify  whether the class is injectable or not in Magento 2 as per the [comment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141196/how-magento-cataloginventory-model-stock-item-can-be-replaced-in-constructor-di/141197#141197).
2. In [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130549/magento-2-cataloginventory-loadbyproduct) answer get is used by object manager, can any one tell me how to convert below class into constructor as a dependency class.
3. How can we treat `get` and `create` into constructor as a dependency classes.

   ```
   $stockItemFactory = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory');
   $stockItem = $stockItemFactory->create();
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually everything is injectable except models that have a table (or more) associated to it.  For example the product model, the order model...
These should not be injected in the constructor because you will end up with the same class instance everywhere you inject it. And this could lead to problems.
When dealing with such classes you should inject the factory into the constructor and instantiate your class using the `$factory->create()` method.
You don't need to write the factories yourself. They will be autogenerated.

You should never use the object manager to instantiate the classes. Even if it works, it's not a good practice and it will make it harder for you to write tests.

`get` from the object manager acts as `Mage::getSingleton` from magento 1 and `create` acts as `Mage::getModel`.

And you can convert your code to use DI like this.

```
protected $stockItemFactory;
public function __construct(
   ....
   \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory $stockItemFactory,
   ....
) {
    ...
    $this->stockItemFactory = $stockItemFactory;
    ....
}
```

Having this set in your constructor, you can use this in your class methods (even in the constructor but below the line I mentioned) in order to instantiate your class:

```
$stockItem = $this->stockItemFactory->create();
```

I hope I covered all your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 @Marius, yes you have covered with brief answer, but a small ambiguity is Mage::getModel('') can be converted to $this->stockItemFactory->create();  but how Mage::getSingleton can be converted/used into a dependency class in Magento 2 as same (objectManager->get)?

Comment: everything you inject in a constructor will be a singleton.  so adding an instance of `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory` to your constructor will be equivalent to `objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterfaceFactory')`. You will always have the same instance of the class even if you provide it in 2 constructors of 2 different classes.